# How to get dynamically attachment image url for <a href> tag?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

So, below is the Wordpress default generated code for an image:

```
<div class="image-section">
  <a href="http://websitename.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/image-1.jpg" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
    <img src="http://websitename.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/image-1.jpg"/>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="image-section">
  <a href="http://websitename.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/image-2.jpg" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
    <img src="http://websitename.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/image-2.jpg"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

I have no idea to get image attachment link for a tag

I can't change URL for each image, Is there any possibilities to get the attachment link for `<a>` instead of the image URL

This is what I am expecting

```
<div class="image-section">
  <a href="current_image_attachment_url" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
    <img src="http://websitename.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/image-1.jpg"/>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="image-section">
  <a href="current_image_attachment_url" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
    <img src="http://websitename.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/image-2.jpg"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "image attachment link for a tag"?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Wordpress creates an attachment page for each image. You can view it from the Media Library by opening an image and clicking the "view attachment page" link.

Comment: Are we talking about using the classic editor? Because when composing a post / page, when you pick an image from the media library, after clicking the image you can set where it's going to link to before inserting it. Or are you talking about something else?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url

Comment: create foreach and return all images in database

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I want to get attachment link on <a> tag  For example: <a href="/walls/full/0/b/6/44764.jpg" target="_blank"><img src=" image link"></a>

Comment: @ChrisG I have already inserted the code more than 50 posts. Now I want to redirect the image to the attachment page.

Comment: @S0HS Can you give me an explanation.

Comment: @ChrisG Main thing is when I click on the image it should go to attachment page.

Comment: I guess redirecting an image link to its attachment page is possible, however [that will break all images on the website (since the browser also gets redirected)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/178103/redirect-image-url-to-a-page-via-htaccess#comment259925_178121). The only feasible solution I can see is to write a PHP script that 1. loads all posts from the DB 2. grabs image links, find the proper attachment URL and replaces it 3. writes back the posts to the DB

Comment: @ChrisG Can you give me a deep explanation in this concept.

Comment: No, sorry, this is tedious stuff and I'm not going to do all the research for you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late to help OP but maybe this will help someone else. It is not necessary to get a whole new link to show the image attachment page dynamically. You're just going to be using the URL for the image itself in the WP library. Since you're already calling that once to show the image on the page, you can simply call it again inside your `a` tag to make it linky.

In the example below I am using ACF Pro and ACF repeater. In the field groups I have set up, the slug for this image field is `'before_image'`. (This was used to show sets of before and after photos.)

Example: To show the image without the link to the attachment page:
`<img src="<?php the_sub_field('before_image') ?>">`

To show the image linked to its own attachment page:

`<a href="<?php the_sub_field('before_image') ?>"><img src="<?php the_sub_field('before_image') ?>"></a>`

As you can see you're calling the same link in both places:
`the_sub_field('before_image')`

No need to rewrite anything. Just call it twice and Bob's your uncle.